# Error al activar funcion popup en jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, popup

Tengo el siguiente código que funciona correctamente y me permite desplegar todos los anuncios publicados en mi web por un usuario y que al hacer click sobre cada uno de ellos se desplegue un popup mas información sobre el mismo. Mi problema es que desarrollé una nueva sección en la que hay un botón debajo de cada anuncio que permite editar el mismo. Lo que pretendo es que al hacer click en cada uno de estos botones, se ejecute una función jquery que cumpla el mismo objetivo que la expresada más arriba. Sin embargo, tengo un error y es que al cliquear este botón, se desplegan todos los popups a la vez y no cada uno en particular como sucedía con la función anterior. Dejo el código que tengo actualmente.

**Código PHP**

```
    <?php
    $CantShow=10;
        $compag = (int)(!isset($_GET['publishpShow'])) ? 1 : $_GET['publishpShow'];
        $TotalReg = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM anuncios");
        $totalr = mysqli_num_rows($TotalReg);
        $TotalRegistro = ceil($totalr/$CantShow);
        $IncNum = (($compag +1)<=$TotalRegistro)?($compag +1):0;
        $consult = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM anuncios WHERE id = '$id' ORDER BY id_pub DESC LIMIT ".(($compag-1)*$CantShow)." , ".$CantShow);
        //$consultA = mysqli_query($conexion, $consult);
    ?>
    <div class="publishmShow">
        <?php
        while($lista = mysqli_fetch_array($consult)){
                $userid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $lista['id']);
                $usuariob = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$userid'");
                $use = mysqli_fetch_array($usuariob);
        ?>
                <div class="publishContainer">
                    <div class="publish">
                        <div class="publishCInfo">
                            <?php $date = $lista['fecha']; ?>
                            <p class="publishCDate">Publicado el <?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date))?> a las <?php echo date('G:i', strtotime($date))?></p> 
                            <div class="publishCZone"><p class="publishCProv">En <?php echo $lista['provincia']?></p> <p class="publishCLoc"><?php echo $lista['localidad']?></p></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="publishPDisplay">
                            <div class="publishCOffer">
                                <p class="publishCQuantity"><?php echo $lista['cantidad']?></p>
                                <p class="publishCCurrency"><?php echo $lista['moneda']?></p>
                            </div>
                            <p class="publishCFee">Fee <?php echo $lista['comision']?>%</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="publishPDetails">
                            <p class="publishCOperation"><?php echo $lista['operacion']?></p>
                            <div class="publishCMethod">
                                <p class="publishCMethodAccepted">Acepta:</p><p class="publishCP2P"><?php echo $lista['p2p']?></p><p class="publishCF2F"><?php echo $lista['f2f']?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="publishOverlay">
                        <div class="publishannounce">
                            <a href="#"class="btn-cerrar-popup"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
                            <?php
                            if($use['id'] == $_SESSION['id']){
                            ?>
                            <div class="publishMyAnnounceNotice">
                            <p>Así veran tu anuncio los demás usuarios. <a href="myannouncements.php?id=<?php echo $use['id'];?>">Editar</a></p>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                            <div class="publishDfirsttwo">
                                <div class="publishDUser">
                                    <div class="publishDPic">
                                    <img class="profpicDpub" src="img/profilepics/<?php echo $use['avatar']?>" alt="Avatar">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="publishDUserProfile">
                                    <p class="publishDTitle"><span>@</span><?php echo $use['usuario']?></p>
                                    <li class="publishDdiviser">
                                        <a><i class="fas fa-chevron-right "></i></a>
                                        <a href="userprofile.php?id=<?php echo $use['id'];?>" class="publishDProfile">Ver perfil</a>
                                    </li>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php 
                                        if($use['criptotop'] != 0) {?>
                                            <div class="publishDCriptoTop">
                                                <div class="publishDcriptotopmedalshow">
                                                    <img class="publishDcriptotopmedal" src= "img/criptotopmedal.png" alt="Usuario Cripto Top"></img>
                                                </div>
                                                <!--<p class="publishDCriptoTopShow">Este usuario es Cripto<span>Top</span>, lo que significa que se caracteriza por su buena atención y su capacidad de venta.</p>-->
                                            </div>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="publishDInfo">
                                    <p class="publishDDate">Publicado el <?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date))?> a las <?php echo date('G:i', strtotime($date))?></p> 
                                    <div class="publishDZone"><p class="publishDProv">En <?php echo $lista['provincia']?> <p class="publishDLoc"><?php echo $lista['localidad']?></p></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="publishDsecondthree">
                                <p class="publishDOperation"><?php echo $lista['operacion']?></p>
                                <div class="publishDOffer">
                                    <p class="publishDQuantity"><?php echo $lista['cantidad']?></p>
                                    <p class="publishDCurrency"><?php echo $lista['moneda']?></p>
                                </div>
                                <p class="publishDFee">Fee <?php echo $lista['comision']?>%</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="publishDthirdone">
                                <span>Métodos aceptados: </span><div class="publishDPayment"><li class="publishDP2P"><?php echo $lista['p2p']?></li><li class="publishDF2F"><?php echo $lista['f2f']?></li></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="publishDcontactbutton">
                                <a href="chat.php?id=<?php echo $use['id']?>">Contactar</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="publishPModify" id="modifyButton">
                        <p>Modificar</p><i class="fa fa-magic" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                <div class="publishPDelete">
                    <input type="submit" id="delete" name="delete" class="deleteButton" value="Eliminar" onclick="confirm();"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
```

**Código JQuery que funciona correctamente: el anuncio popup se desplega al cliquear sobre "publishContainer"**

```
    $(function() {
    $('.publishContainer').on('click', function(e) {
        $(this).find('.publishOverlay').addClass('active');
        $(this).find('.publishannounce').addClass('active');
        $(this).find('.publish').addClass('active');
        $(this).find('.publishCriptoTop').addClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
    $('.btn-cerrar-popup').on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).closest('.publishOverlay').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('.publishannounce').removeClass('active');
        $('.publish').removeClass('active');
        $('.publishCriptoTop').removeClass('active');
        $('.publishContainer').removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

**Código jquery que no logro hacer funcionar: el anuncio popup debería desplegarse al hacer click en "publishPModify"**

```
$(function() {
    $('.publishPModify').on('click', function(e) {
        var publishContainer = $('.publishContainer');
        // Obtener ventana del anuncio y mostrar
        $(publishContainer).find('.publishOverlay').addClass('active');
        $(publishContainer).find('.publishannounce').addClass('active');
        $(publishContainer).find('.publish').addClass('active');
        $(publishContainer).find('.publishCriptoTop').addClass('active');
        $(publishContainer).addClass('active');
    });
    $('.btn-cerrar-popup').on('click', function(e) {
        var publishContainer = $('.publishContainer');
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).closest('.publishOverlay').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('.publishannounce').removeClass('active');
        $('.publish').removeClass('active');
        $('.publishCriptoTop').removeClass('active');
        $(publishContainer).removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Aclaraciones: 1. El código PHP aquí es uno solo para no ocupar tanto espacio en la pregunta. Sin embargo, en mi web es el mismo pero en dos secciones diferentes. El código que funciona no incluye el div "publishPModify" que sería el botón de 'editar', sino que ese está incluido en la sección en la cual estoy trabajando actualmente y con la cual no logro hacer que funcione el código jquery. 2. Los códigos jquery estan alojados en dos archivos .JS diferentes, llamando respectivamente a cada uno de ellos en las diferentes secciones de mi web.
Necesito entender cómo puedo hacer que funcione el código que actualmente no está funcionando correctamente. Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: con que metodo despliegas/abres el popup???
no es mejor usar modals??

Comment: Lo hago a través de una funcion onclick que responde a cada anuncio. Como seria el método que dices?

Comment: depende de la version de bootstrap que estes usando...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que con `$('.publishContainer');` *jQuery* buscará en todo el documento y va a devolver el primer elemento que coincida con el selector. Debes buscar el contenedor padre desde el elemento que dispara el evento, con el método [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).

```
$(function() {
    $('.publishPModify').on('click', function(e) {
        // $(this) es el elemento que disparó el evento
        let publishContainer = $(this).closest('.publishContainer');
        // Obtener ventana del anuncio y mostrar
        $(publishContainer).find('.publishOverlay').addClass('active');
        $(publishContainer).find('.publishannounce').addClass('active');
        $(publishContainer).find('.publish').addClass('active');
        $(publishContainer).find('.publishCriptoTop').addClass('active');
        $(publishContainer).addClass('active');
    });
    $('.btn-cerrar-popup').on('click', function(e) {
        let publishContainer = $(this).closest('.publishContainer');
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).closest('.publishOverlay').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('.publishannounce').removeClass('active');
        $('.publish').removeClass('active');
        $('.publishCriptoTop').removeClass('active');
        $(publishContainer).removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Algunas recomendaciones:

- Declara tus variables con [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) para que solo estén disponibles en cada bloque
- Podrías tener una sola ventana (o popup) para controlar todos los anuncios y, al abrirla, tomar los datos necesarios desde `.publishContainer` para mostrarlos en esa ventana. Es un poco más trabajo en Javascript, pero resultará mucho más eficiente al reducir el código HTML creado y enviado desde PHP al navegador.

Comment: Funciona a la perfección si incluyo el div "publishPModify" dentro de "publishContainer". Si lo dejo por fuera no funciona el evento. Así que muchas gracias. :)